# Как ускорить программу о выводе наборов цветов кубиков?

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, множества

**Условие задачи:**

Аня и Боря любят играть в разноцветные кубики, причем у каждого из них свой набор и в каждом наборе все кубики различны по цвету. Однажды дети заинтересовались, сколько существуют цветов таких, что кубики каждого цвета присутствуют в обоих наборах. Для этого они занумеровали все цвета случайными числами. На этом их энтузиазм иссяк, поэтому вам предлагается помочь им в оставшейся части.

Номер любого цвета — это целое число в пределах от 0 до 109.

*Входные данные*

В первой строке входного файла записаны числа N и M — количество кубиков у Ани и Бори соответственно. В следующих N строках заданы номера цветов кубиков Ани. В последних M строках номера цветов кубиков Бори.

*Выходные данные*

Выведите сначала количество, а затем отсортированные по возрастанию номера цветов таких, что кубики каждого цвета есть в обоих наборах, затем количество и отсортированные по возрастанию номера остальных цветов у Ани, потом количество и отсортированные по возрастанию номера остальных цветов у Бори.

**Вот мой код:**

```
total = list(map(int, input().split()))
ann = []
boris = []

for i in range(total[0]):
    ann.append(int(input()))

for i in range(total[1]):
    boris.append(int(input()))

both = []
for i in ann:
    if i in boris:
       both.append(i)

print(len(both))
both.sort()
for i in both:
    print(i, end=" ")
if len(both) != 0:
    print()

o_ann = []
for i in ann:
    if not i in boris:
        o_ann.append(i)

print(len(o_ann))
o_ann.sort()
for i in o_ann:
    print(i, end=" ")
if len(o_ann) != 0:
    print()

o_boris = []
for i in boris:
    if not i in ann:
        o_boris.append(i)

print(len(o_boris))
o_boris.sort()
for i in o_boris:
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Программа работает чуть больше двух секунд. Как можно ускорить процесс?

Comment: в чём заключается ваш вопрос? сформулируйте, пожалуйста, и внесите необходимые дополнения, нажав [edit] под текстом вопроса.

Comment: "отсортированные по возрастанию" - а где это у вас учитывается?

Comment: Как ускорить программу, которая имплементирует математический алгоритм? Очевидно же: придумать более эффективный алгоритм.

Comment: Написать алгоритм на С++  или вовсе на ASM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался. Оказывается всё можно было сделать намного проще, используя встроенные функции:

```
ann, boris = list(map(int, input().split()))
a = set()
b = set()
for i in range(ann):
    a.add(int(input()))
for i in range(boris):
    b.add(int(input()))

print(len(a.intersection(b)))
print(*sorted(a.intersection(b)))
print(len(a.difference(b)))
print(*sorted(a.difference(b)))
print(len(b.difference(a)))
print(*sorted(b.difference(a)))
```

Comment: `intersection()` и `difference()` для множеств можно заменить на операции `&` и `-` соответственно: `a & b`, `a - b`, `b - a`.

Comment: Когда и такой способ Вам покажется медленным, то самое время почитать про модуль numpy :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: для 110 цветов, `numpy` модуль вероятно дольше импортироваться будет, чем оставшаяся часть программы выполняться.

Answer (score 2):

Если оба списка сначала отсортировать, то для определения их пересечения за линейное время (но с учётом первой сортировки получится `O(n*lb(n))`) следует использовать алгоритм слияния из merge sort. Берём два итератора и сравниваем их значения. Если значения равны, помещаем цвет в результат и переходим к следующему элементу в обоих списках (цвета там уникальны, поэтому повтор рассматривать не надо). Иначе переходим к следующему элементу в списке, содержащем меньшее из двух чисел (которое помещаем в соответствующий список результата).

Comment: не вижу где указано, что списки отсортированы -- "занумеровали случайными числами"  говорит об обратном (хотя для `110` цветов не имеет значения разница между `O(n)` и `O(n * log n)`).

Comment: @jfs, я невнимательный и перепутал входные данные с выходными. Удалить ответ или оставить?

Comment: @jfs, вообще-то для 110 цветов даже за квадрат всё будет хорошо :)

Comment: да, я тоже не понимаю, как две секунды набежало. Merge sort полезно упомянуть в контексте задачи (поправить, только ответ, чтобы ввод отсортировать).

Comment: @jfs, а насколько эффективно сначала сортировать? Тем более, можно сортировать один список, а дальше использовать бинпоиск по нему. А ещё, я не прочитал, что нужно вывести 3 результата, а не один :(

Comment: более конкретно здесь не имеет смысла рассматривать, важно что результат правильный возвращает (а сам алгоритм хоть с [внешней сортировкой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16954837/4279) может работать, а результат в три внешних файла писать).

Comment: @jfs, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Входные данные можно с помощью [диаграммы Венна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0) проиллюстрировать. Например:

```
     ___________      ___________
   /             \  /             \
  /               \/               \
 /                /\                \
 |       Аня     /  \     Боря       |
 |              | 45 |               |
 |  5 10 20 25  | 15 |  3 6 9 12 18  |
 \               \  /               /
  \               \/               /
   \              /\              /
    \ __________ /  \ __________ /
```

Простой код, чтобы получить соответствующие части диаграммы:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
N, M = map(int, input().split())
A = {int(input()) for _ in range(N)}
B = {int(input()) for _ in range(M)}
for S in [A & B, A - B, B - A]:
    print(len(S))
    print(*sorted(S))
```

#### [Результат](http://ideone.com/m2b3iJ)

```
2
15 45
4
5 10 20 25
5
3 6 9 12 18
```

Так как все кубики различны по цвету внутри наборов и число цветов ограничено (и маленькое), то время выполнения здесь вероятно ограничено временем старта самого Питон-интерпретатора и вводом/выводом -- а временем на сами вычисления можно пренебречь.